# Jquery Serialize not working to post to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i'm can't save my data in databse when i'm something to do with my input or select html tag.
Whats wrong guys??

Ajax

```
$("input, select, textarea").on('change blur' ,function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/karyawan-diterima/edit',
       data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
       success:function(sukses){
          //alert(data);
          console.log(sukses);
          $('#sukses').show();

          setInterval(function() {
            $('#sukses').fadeOut();
          }, 2500);
       }
    });
});
```

Update Controller

```
$id = $request->id;

    $k = karyawan::where('id', $id) -> first();
    $d = detail_karyawan::where('id_karyawan', $id) -> first();

    $k->nama = $request->nama;
    $k->telp = $request->telp;
    $k->bagian = $request->bagian;
    $k->nik_lama = $request->nik_lama;
    $k->nik_baru = $request->nik_baru;
    $k->jk = $request->jk;
    $k->alamat = $request->alamat;

    $k->update;

    $sukses = 'success';
    return response()->json($sukses, 200);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLiC6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not `saving` or `updating` your data..You are using `update` as a property of `$k` instead of `update` function.

**Change**

```
$k->update;
```

**to**

```
$k->update();
```